# How do I know if my meteor app is running in spiderable environment?

Tags: meteor

I need to know if my meteor application has been executed using the spiderable package. Ideally have an environment variable such as "isSpiderable" (boolean).

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spiderable package works by executing your app client-side code inside a PhantomJS process, so you can test against the presence of the PhantomJS footprint inside the user agent signature.

```
function isSpiderable(){
  return /PhantomJS/.test(window.navigator.userAgent);
}
```

Have a look to this article too : http://engineering.shapesecurity.com/2015/01/detecting-phantomjs-based-visitors.html